# How to parcel a Spanned?

Tags: android, parcelable, spanned

I try to parcel a Spanned but when I add bold spans, the test I wrote is not passing anymore.

Here is the test :

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)     
public class DNTest {             
    private String testData;             
    private Spanned spanned;             
    private Intent intent;     
    private Class<NI> itemClass;                      

    @Before             
    public void initialize() throws IOException {                 
        testData = Tests.readTestData(getInstrumentation(), “file.json);
        intent = new Intent("ACTION");                 
        spanned = getDisplayableString(“thing”, "Wojtek Wntrzak");
        assertThat(testData).isNotNull().isNotEmpty();             
    }      

         @Parameterized.Parameters             
    public static Collection<Object[]> testNI() {                 
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {                         
            { LANI.class },                         
            { FANI.class },                         
            { ACNI.class },                         
            { CRNI.class },                 
        });             
    }                      

    public DNTest(Class<NI> nItemClass){                 
        itemClass = nItemClass;             
    }                      

    @Test             
    public void testParcelable() {                 
        NI notification = mGson.fromJson(testData, itemClass);               
        DN dN = new DN(spanned,      intent,      notification);                          
        Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        parcel.writeString(dN.getClass().getName());              
        dN.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);                 
        parcel.setDataPosition(0);                          
        final DN parcelled = parcel.readParcelable(dN.getClass().getClassLoader());                     
        assertThat(parcelled).isNotNull();                 
        assertEquals(parcelled.getSpanned(), spanned);                 
        assertEquals(new Intent.FilterComparison(parcelled.getIntent()),                              
        new Intent.FilterComparison(intent));                 
        assertEquals(parcelled.getItem(), notification);                          
        assertThat(dN).isNotNull();                 
        assertParcelableCorrect(dN);             
    }

    private Spanned getDisplayableString(String name, String actor) {         
        final String string;         
        string = actor + " blablabla " + name;         
        SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(string);         
        Notifications.boldify(string, spannable, actor);         
        Notifications.boldify(string, spannable, name);  
        Spanned spanned = spannable;            
        return spanned;     
    }
}
```

It passes when I comment the 2 lines with the boldify function.

Here is the boldify function :

```
public static void boldify(String source, SpannableString spannable, String text) {         
     int start = source.indexOf(text);         
     if (start == -1) {             
          return;         
     }              
     spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), start, start + text.length(),  Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);     
 }
```

And I tried 3 ways of parcelling the Spanned but none of them worked :

```
dest.writeString(Html.toHtml(mSpanned));
mSpanned = Html.fromHtml(in.readString());     

dest.writeValue(mSpanned);     
mSpanned = (Spanned) in.readValue(DisplayableNotification.class.getClassLoader());         

TextUtils.writeToParcel(mSpanned, dest, flags);     
mSpanned = (Spanned) TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(in);
```